# Is Chrome Javascript evaluating boolean expressions correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, boolean, evaluation

It's a popular pattern to assign a default value:

```
var aBool = '' || false;
var aString = false || '';
```

The above would give `aBool` boolean the value of `false`, and aString the value of an empty string, at least in Chrome's and FF's console. That's contrary to:

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand can be converted to true; if both can be converted to false,
>   returns false.
>   source: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

That's actually handy, but is it correct?

Comment: No, it isn't and actually makes no sense. Feel free to edit that page ("Thus..." part should be removed).

Comment: "Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`" is the important part of the sentence

Comment: What's wrong, seems correct to me? *If used with booleans*, it returns true if either operand is true, or false if both are false?

Comment: "returns true if either operand can be converted to true",  but it's not true, it's false, so should return '', if you do true || '', you will get true.

Comment: I've corrected the page. Thanks to point the edit option out, @georg

Comment: And again, what was wrong with it? If both values are **booleans**, and both values are `false`, it returns `false`. An empty string is not a boolean?

Comment: The page stated "it returns true" which was not always true.

Comment: It only says that when both operands are Boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

From that same web page, it says:

> Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are:
>
> - null;
> - NaN;
> - 0;
> - empty string ("");
> - undefined.

In your first example, you have an empty string, so it converts to `false` when converted to a Boolean. Since `expr1` can't be converted to `true`, the expression returns `expr2`, which is `false`.

In your second example, `expr1` is `false`, so it returns `expr2`, which is `''`. The conversion to `Boolean` is just used for determining which expression should be returned, it doesn't return the converted value.

Comment: Thanks, I know what it does, just confused withe doc. It's been fixed now, I feel relieved ;)